# Pandoc - Abbreviations in Latex

Tags: acronyms, pandoc

I would like to create a list of abbreviations with `pandoc`. I found out that the standard markdown convert doesn't support abbreviations. But then I found `markdown_phpextra` which supports abbreviations. But I can't make it work for me.

I am using an abbreviation this way:

`*[e.g.]: for example`

My pandoc command is this:

`pandoc --standalone --from=markdown_phpextra --output=example.pdf example.md`

But pandoc doesn't even seem to convert abbreviations. Any suggestion how to solve my problem or a workaround for this?

Comment: This should probably be asked either in [Pandoc group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/pandoc-discuss) or filled in as an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues).

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: This could be solved by a Pandoc filter which modifies the abstract syntax tree of a document before it is converted to LaTeX.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [Pandoc Manual](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-abbreviations),

> Note that the pandoc document model does not support abbreviations, so if this extension is enabled, abbreviation keys are simply skipped (as opposed to being parsed as paragraphs).

As @wilx suggested, it's better to bring this up as an issue on [Pandoc's Github page](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues).

However, you may try MultiMarkdown's implementation of [abbreviations](http://fletcher.github.io/MultiMarkdown-5/abbreviations.html) which uses the `acronym` package.

The following markdown source,

```
The HTML specification
is maintained by the W3C.

*[HTML]: Hyper Text Markup Language
*[W3C]:  World Wide Web Consortium
```

provides the resultant LaTeX code:

```
\newacro{w3cworldwidewebconsortium}[W3C]{World Wide Web Consortium}
\newacro{htmlhypertextmarkuplanguage}[HTML]{Hyper Text Markup Language}
The \ac{htmlhypertextmarkuplanguage} specification
is maintained by the \ac{w3cworldwidewebconsortium}.
```